# Nginx + gunicorn Django 1.9 CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-csrf

**Background :**
I am trying to configure cloudflare **flexible** SSL with django.
Browser <-HTTPS-> Cloudflare <-HTTP-> Nginx <--> Gunicorn

**Issue :**
I am getting **CSRF verification failed. Request aborted for admin panel login** - For now this is the only POST request on my website.
(belive me, I have skimmed through tons of posts here and on gist but nothing seems to be working for me :( )

**Configurations :**

**Nginx -**

```
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;

real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/webapps/run/SBWebsite.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

**Django - settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
PREPEND_WWW = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

**Cloudflare DNS -**

```
A domain.com  points to <ip> Automatic
CNAME www is an alias of domain.com Automatic

Page rule is set to always use HTTPS
```

**Update #1**
Everything works fine from **Chrome Incognito** mode !

**Update #2 (Solution)**
Seems like it was cookie issue, I cleared all cookies from my browser and now its working fine!!
Partly it could also be **SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER** issue as it was wrong in my settings.py

Comment: Is the page cached by cloudflare?

Comment: check if cloudflare is not replacing POST requests to GET

Comment: @frlan I have disabled html caching in cloudflare

Comment: @Jerzyk I just confirmed from nginx logs, that POST is NOT been replaced by GET

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error in a comparable setup without Cloudflare: Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Django.

I fixed it by changing this Nginx setting:
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`
To this:
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

So that the scheme is not hard-coded, but instead derived from the request.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have made a mistake while naming http-header. You have to ensure that the name of the **X-Forwarded-Proto** header is correct in both: *nginx* configuration and *Django*'s settings.py.

So you should modify your **settings.py** file by replacing the line:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

with this one:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

---

Or you can add to nginx configuration file the line below:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
```

Comment: My location block looks like this now, is this correct ?  
I tried to restart nginx and gunicorn but the error persists.

`location / {
proxy_pass http://unix:/var/webapps/run/SBWebsite.sock;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}`

Comment: I've editted answer just now. It seems you have mistake in the header name. Try to use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in settings.py with your original nginx configuration file.

Comment: I tried both ways, but still the error persists.
Even If I disable SSL ( set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE - FALSE) the error is still there.

Comment: I just tried from chrome incognito mode and there was no csrf error.
But when I try from normal window, I still get the csrf error.

Comment: @John, try to clean your browser's cache and cookies associated with your site